# Laptop screen flashing intermittent

Tags: nvidia, graphics, screen, asus, flicker

I seem to have a 50/50 chance that when I boot up my screen will kind of flash/flicker every 5 seconds or so. If it is going to flash, it starts when the laptop is booting up, I imagine when the graphics drivers are loading, as you can see the difference in screen brightness of the commands loading whilst using `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nouveau.modeset=0"`

My system will not boot with the nouveau driver, so I have disabled it and tried the recommended 440 driver, as well as the 435. I am currently using the 450 NVIDIA driver which is the only driver that will work with the x server software. All three drivers have the same flashing issue.

I've tried doing a fresh install with the same issues and I have tried updating my kernel to 5.8rc7.

My only resolution is to reset the laptop.

ASUS Rog G15 Ryzen 7 with NVIDIA GTX1660ti

ubuntu 20.04lts

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version 
GA502IU.216
```

`free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.4Gi        12Gi        43Mi       1.4Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

https://justpaste.it/8c8x1 - I've attached this if the below formatting isn't that readable.

`sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: GA502IU.217
       date: 08/03/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: 8ATF1G64HZ-3G2J1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: 8ATF1G64HZ-3G2J1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: 24F55C3D
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: e
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3`
```

430 install failed log DKMS make.log

````
Tue 18 Aug 20:54:05 BST 2020
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
  SYMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
  SYMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o
 CONFTEST: INIT_WORK
 CONFTEST: hash__remap_4k_pfn
 CONFTEST: list_is_first
 CONFTEST: set_pages_uc
 CONFTEST: set_memory_uc
 CONFTEST: set_memory_array_uc
 CONFTEST: acquire_console_sem
 CONFTEST: console_lock
 CONFTEST: ioremap_cache
 CONFTEST: ioremap_wc
 CONFTEST: acpi_walk_namespace
 CONFTEST: sg_alloc_table
 CONFTEST: pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot
 CONFTEST: get_num_physpages
 CONFTEST: efi_enabled
 CONFTEST: pde_data
 CONFTEST: proc_remove
 CONFTEST: pm_vt_switch_required
 CONFTEST: xen_ioemu_inject_msi
 CONFTEST: phys_to_dma
 CONFTEST: get_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: write_cr4
 CONFTEST: of_get_property
 CONFTEST: of_find_node_by_phandle
 CONFTEST: of_node_to_nid
 CONFTEST: pnv_pci_get_npu_dev
 CONFTEST: of_get_ibm_chip_id
 CONFTEST: for_each_online_node
 CONFTEST: node_end_pfn
 CONFTEST: pci_bus_address
 CONFTEST: pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: pci_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: register_cpu_notifier
 CONFTEST: cpuhp_setup_state
 CONFTEST: dma_map_resource
 CONFTEST: backlight_device_register
 CONFTEST: register_acpi_notifier
 CONFTEST: timer_setup
 CONFTEST: pci_enable_msix_range
 CONFTEST: do_gettimeofday
 CONFTEST: kernel_read
 CONFTEST: kernel_write
 CONFTEST: address_space_init_once
 CONFTEST: kbasename
 CONFTEST: fatal_signal_pending
 CONFTEST: list_cut_position
 CONFTEST: vzalloc
 CONFTEST: wait_on_bit_lock_argument_count
 CONFTEST: bitmap_clear
 CONFTEST: usleep_range
 CONFTEST: radix_tree_empty
 CONFTEST: radix_tree_replace_slot
 CONFTEST: pnv_npu2_init_context
 CONFTEST: drm_dev_unref
 CONFTEST: drm_reinit_primary_mode_group
 CONFTEST: get_user_pages_remote
 CONFTEST: get_user_pages
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_lookup
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_state_ref_counting
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_res_obj
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms
 CONFTEST: drm_connector_funcs_have_mode_in_name
 CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn
 CONFTEST: drm_framebuffer_get
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_get
 CONFTEST: drm_dev_put
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_of_node_to_nid
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_map_sg_attrs
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: acpi_op_remove
 CONFTEST: outer_flush_all
 CONFTEST: scatterlist
 CONFTEST: file_operations
 CONFTEST: vm_operations_struct
 CONFTEST: atomic_long_type
 CONFTEST: file_inode
 CONFTEST: task_struct
 CONFTEST: kuid_t
 CONFTEST: dma_ops
 CONFTEST: swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: dma_map_ops
 CONFTEST: noncoherent_swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: vm_fault_present
 CONFTEST: vm_fault_has_address
 CONFTEST: backlight_properties_type
 CONFTEST: vm_insert_pfn_prot
 CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn_prot
 CONFTEST: vm_ops_fault_removed_vma_arg
 CONFTEST: vmbus_channel_has_ringbuffer_page
 CONFTEST: fault_flags
 CONFTEST: atomic64_type
 CONFTEST: address_space
 CONFTEST: backing_dev_info
 CONFTEST: mm_context_t
 CONFTEST: node_states_n_memory
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_present
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_bus_type
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_irq
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_name
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_legacy_dev_list
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_set_busid
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_connectors_changed
 CONFTEST: drm_init_function_args
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_connector_list_update_has_merge_type_bits_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_master_drop_has_from_release_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_unload_has_int_return_type
 CONFTEST: kref_has_refcount_of_type_refcount_t
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_crtc_destroy_state_has_crtc_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_helper_funcs_has_atomic_enable
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_object_find_has_file_priv_arg
 CONFTEST: dma_buf_owner
 CONFTEST: drm_connector_list_iter
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_swap_state_has_stall_arg
 CONFTEST: dom0_kernel_present
 CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_hyperv_available
 CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_kvm_build
 CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_build
 CONFTEST: pm_runtime_available
 CONFTEST: drm_available
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_available
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_inc
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_dec_and_test
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-instance.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-acpi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-chrdev.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-cray.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-dma.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-gvi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mempool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.o
In file included from ./include/linux/bitops.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/kernel.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-lock.h:16,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:19,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:14:
./include/linux/bits.h:8: warning: "BIT" redefined
    8 | #define BIT(nr)   (UL(1) << (nr))
      | 
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:12:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nvmisc.h:58: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   58 | #define BIT(b)                  (1U<<(b))
      | 
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-pat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-procfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-usermap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-vm.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-chrdev.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-instance.c:13:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:14:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-dma.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-acpi.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-cray.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:42:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
   42 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-gvi.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c: In function ‘nvidia_init_module’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:786:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
  786 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.c:882:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
  882 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-i2c.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mempool.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c:13:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c:39:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
   39 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c: In function ‘nv_init_module’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c:349:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
  349 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c: In function ‘nv_exit_module’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.c:364:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
  364 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-chrdev.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-pat.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-instance.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-cray.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-procfs.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.c:19:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
   19 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES == 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mempool.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-usermap.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-gvi.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-pat.o] Error 1
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c: In function ‘nv_encode_caching’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:338:16: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  338 |             if (NV_ALLOW_CACHING(memory_type))
      |                ^
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:340:9: note: here
  340 |         default:
      |         ^~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-i2c.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-usermap.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-vm.c:14:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-frontend.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-dma.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-procfs.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-vm.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv-acpi.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build/nvidia/nv.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1731: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.09/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:79: modules] Error 2```
````

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question to include the outputs. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @heynnema - Just tagging you here as I was unsure if you would get the notification from my response to your answer (it wouldn't let me tag you there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS Rog G15

You have BIOS version GA502IU.216.

There's a newer BIOS available, version GA502IU.217, dated 8/6/2020, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/me-en/Laptops/ROG-Zephyrus-G15/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Nvidia**

It sounds like you have the Nvidia 450 driver.

Confirm that you've selected a supported screen resolution, and 60hz refresh rate, in your `Displays` settings panel. Note: In Europe, the refresh rate might be 50hz.

Their website indicates a different version driver for your Nvidia GTX 1660ti. Version 430.09 can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

[image]

**swap**

Let's increase your /swapfile to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Nouveau**

Remember to change /etc/default/grub...

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nouveau.modeset=0"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

`sudo update-grub`

**Kernel**

Uninstall kernel 5.8rc7, and revert to the stock 20.04.1 kernel. Note that `rc7` indicates a `release candidate 7`, and should never be installed unless you're a developer who wants to test pre-release software.

****Update #1:****

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility problems.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

<strike>**Update #2:**</strike>

Now, for the Nvidia driver...

Switch to the nouveau driver, or switch to the internal Intel video card, and then uninstall all the Nvidia stuff, and try and reinstall the Nvidia 430.09 driver again.

**Note**: Nvidia supplies their own uninstaller. You can run that first, and then run my commands to make sure there are no leftovers.

`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep -v "un "` # note the space after un

This will give you a list of all the Nvidia package names.

Then do:

`sudo apt-get purge package_name` # for each package name

And re-install 430.09.

**Update #3:**

Along with the other mods, it's running fine on kernel 5.9-rc1 and Nvidia 450.

Comment: The drivers through the ubuntu additional driver software install okay, which are 335 or 340 if that is anything to go with.

Comment: @Zak We can always come back to those versions... but Nvidia Support will ask you what version you have installed, and if you don't have the latest, 450.xx, then they'll tell you to try it. So... we might as well try it first.

Comment: @Zak Status please...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111943/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-laptop-screen-flashing-intermittent).

Comment: @heynnema I will get back to you tonight/tomorrow as I am at work today